# Proof that $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology is not a union of disjoint segments.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Number of segments is greater than 1. I want to show there exists a point that does not belong to union of possibly infinite  number of disjoint segments. For finite number of segments it is evident - any point that is left to leftmost segment will work. For infinite number of points one should do something else. Any ideas?

My guess that some iterative process should be used, something like nested interval theorem, however I do not see how to apply it and I am not sure it will work.

I hope there should be very simple and elegant proof of this statement.

UPD - intervals are closed, bounded and have more than one point.

Comment: Hedgehog what do you mean by segments?

Comment: @all closed interval, right

Comment: @Hedgehog ... and $[a,a]$ is not allowed

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen yes, otherwise it would be possible to construct counterexample

Comment: @Hedgehog from what you are saying in your question it seems like the intervals must be bounded. Is this true? It doesn't really matter either way but I just want to make sure it is clear what you mean/are thinking of.

Comment: Yes, they must be bounded, closed contain more than one point. I will clarify the question now.

Comment: @xavierm02 these do not seem to be disjoint.

Comment: @mookid : Right >_<

Answer (score 3):

Assume $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{i\in I}[a_i,b_i]$ with $a_i<b_i$ for all $i\in I$ and the intervals pairwise disjoint. Then each interval contains a rational number, so that the index set $I$ can at most be countable, wlog. $I=\mathbb N$.
Let $J_0=\mathbb R$.
Given $J_n$, let $[a_i,b_i]$, $[a_j,b_j]$ be the first two intervals containing an interior point of $J_n$. Then let $J_{n+1}=[\min\{b_i,b_j\},\max\{a_i,a_j\}]$.
Then for each $n\ge1$, $J_n$ is a bounded closed interval and the nested sequence of closed intervals $\{J_n\}$ contains at least one point $c$. Show that $c$ is not covered by the given closed intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Any disjoint family of closed intervals is countable so list them $I_n$, $n \geq 1$. Let $I'_n$ be $I_n$ without its end points. Let $C = \mathbb{R} \backslash \bigcup_n I'_n$. Then $C$ is a closed set without isolated points (Why?). Hence it contains a perfect set. So $\bigcup_n I_n$ misses all but countably many points of $C$.